For which lattices L does the cluster of Voronoi regions abutting that of the origin have a lattice tiling of euclidean space?
Let L be a n-dimensional lattice (a discrete cocompact subgroup of n-space).
Let V0 denote the Voronoi region of the origin, and let C denote the union of V0 with all the Voronoi regions that share a facet (an (n-1)-face) with V0.
Is there a characterization — or better, a classification — of the lattices L for which there exists a sublattice L' whose translations of the cluster C tile n-space?
For example, for L = the Gaussian integers in the complex plane, C is a plus-sign made of 5 squares; for L = the Eisenstein integers, C is a rosette of 7 regular hexagons. In each case there is a sublattice L' of L whose translations of C tile the complex plane.
Edit: I'm most interested in the case where all the "Voronoi vectors" (the vectors of L whose midpoints lie on the boundary of V0) are of the same length, as in the above examples, as well as in the D3 lattice, whose Voronoi region is the rhombic dodecahedron.
